# pl/sql trigger what is wrong in my code

Tags: plsql

Write a trigger emp_dept_hist_trg that monitors the employee table as follows.
- the OLD_DEPARTMENT_NAME is always '(New Hire)'.
- If the new department_id is NULL, the NEW_DEPARTMENT_NAME will be '---'.
When an employee changes his/her department (the old department_id is not equal to the new department_id), the trigger automatically inserts a row (record) into the emp_dept_hist table. (If both the old department_id and new department_id are NULL (from NULL department to NULL department), the trigger does not insert a row (record) into the emp_dept_hist table.)
- Find the old department name from the department table based on the old   department_id.
- If the old department_id is NULL, the OLD_DEPARTMENT_NAME will be '---'.
- Find the new department name from the department table based on the new department_id.
- If the new department_id is NULL, the NEW_DEPARTMENT_NAME will be '---'.
- The SYSDATE can be used in the EFFECTIVE_DATE column.

```
actual table:
CREATE TABLE emp_dept_hist

(

EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,

EMPLOYEE_NAME VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,

OLD_DEPARTMENT_NAME VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,

NEW_DEPARTMENT_NAME VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,

EFFECTIVE_DATE DATE NOT NULL

);
```

My Code:

```
Create or Replace
    TRIGGER emp_dept_hist_trg
    AFTER UPDATE or DELETE ON employee
    FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
    v_count NUMBER;
    old_department_name varchar2(30);
    new_department_name varchar2(30);
    BEGIN

INSERT INTO emp_DEPT_HIST 
VALUES(:OLD.employee_id, 
:OLD.employee_name, 
old_department_name, 
new_department_name, 
effective_date);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('1 row copied.');

select department_name
INTO old_department_name 
from department
where department.department_id = :OLD.department_id ;

Select department_name 
into new_department_name 
from department
where :NEW.department_id = department.department_id;

SELECT COUNT(*) 
INTO v_count
FROM emp_dept_hist;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total records: ' || to_char(v_count));
END emp_dept_hist_trg;
```

when i try to run this code its giving me an error
   PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here

whats wrong with my code.

Comment: You seem to be populating old_department_name and new_department_name after you used them in the insert. That doesn't seem to be correct.

Comment: Additionally, this is a `FOR EACH ROW` trigger, which means it runs exactly once for each row that is updated or deleted. You can not run it standalone and the last v_count will always be one. And you do not initialize `effective_date` with a value.